# Rebex: Transfer Files From Ftp/Sftp To Ftp/Sftp

Tags: ftp, ftps, rebex

Is there a method using the Rebex ftp library to directly transfer files between 2 ftp servers without having to download locally and then push to the second site?

Comment: adding answer: http://forum.rebex.net/questions/4132/transfer-files-from-ftp-sftp-to-ftp-sftp

Answer (score 1):

See the Link on the Rebex forum: http://forum.rebex.net/questions/4132/transfer-files-from-ftp-sftp-to-ftp-sftp